# Create Mailing labels in Asp.Net with iTextSharp PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I have a scenario like, I need to create a PDF with Mailing labels. All the page properties are user defined say No of Rows per page, No Columns, Page Height, Width, Left margin etc... Along this, I may need to leave-out certain number of cells for re-using the used page. Is there any example code on this??

Comment: What's wrong with using `PdfPTable`? Have you tried without succeeding? If so, what was your problem?

Comment: Can send me any sample code ??

Answer (score 3):

May be this help you.

```
using System;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using System.Diagnostics;

protected void btnGeneratePDFFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Create document
Document doc = new  Document();
//Create PDF Table
PdfPTable tableLayout = new PdfPTable(4);

//Create a PDF file in specific path
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("Sample-PDF-File.pdf"), FileMode.Create));

//Open the PDF document
doc.Open();

//Add Content to PDF
doc.Add(Add_Content_To_PDF(tableLayout));

// Closing the document
doc.Close();

btnOpenPDFFile.Enabled = true;
btnGeneratePDFFile.Enabled = false;
  }

private PdfPTable Add_Content_To_PDF(PdfPTable tableLayout)
{
float[] headers = { 20, 20, 30, 30 };  //Header Widths
tableLayout.SetWidths(headers);        //Set the pdf headers
tableLayout.WidthPercentage = 80;       //Set the PDF File witdh percentage

   //Add Title to the PDF file at the top
   tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Creating PDF file using    iTextsharp", new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 13, 1, new iTextSharp.text.Color(153, 51, 0)))) { Colspan = 4, Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 20, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER });         

   //Add header
AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Cricketer Name");
AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Height");
AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Born On");
AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Parents");           

//Add body
AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "Sachin Tendulkar");
AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "1.65 m");
AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "April 24, 1973");
AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "Ramesh Tendulkar, Rajni Tendulkar");

AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "Mahendra Singh Dhoni");
AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "1.75 m");
AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "July 7, 1981");
AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "Devki Devi, Pan Singh");

AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "Virender Sehwag");
AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "1.70 m");
AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "October 20, 1978");
AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "Aryavir Sehwag, Vedant Sehwag");

AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "Virat Kohli");
AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "1.75 m");
AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "November 5, 1988");
AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "Saroj Kohli, Prem Kohli");

return tableLayout;
}

// Method to add single cell to the header
private static void AddCellToHeader(PdfPTable tableLayout,string cellText)
{          
tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText, new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 8, 1, iTextSharp.text.Color.WHITE))) {HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER, Padding=5, BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(0, 51, 102) });
}

// Method to add single cell to the body
private static void AddCellToBody(PdfPTable tableLayout, string cellText)
{           
tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText, new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 8, 1, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK))) { HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER,Padding = 5, BackgroundColor = iTextSharp.text.Color.WHITE });
}
```

btnGeneratePDFFile_Click

In this method I am creating the PDF file in a specific location. Then I am calling the Add_Content_To_PDF method.

Add_Content_To_PDF

In this method I am giving the sizes of the cells as well as PDF file width and then I am adding content to the PDF file usigng the two methods AddCellToHeader and AddCellToBody.

AddCellToHeader

In this method I am adding a single cell to the PDF header with some style.

AddCellToBody

In this method I am adding a single cell to the PDF body with some style.

Now in the Open PDF button click write the following code to open the PDF that has been created:

```
protected void btnOpenPDFFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Open the PDF file
Process.Start(Server.MapPath("Sample-PDF-File.pdf"));
btnGeneratePDFFile.Enabled = true;
btnOpenPDFFile.Enabled = false;
}
```